# Executing for loop, exit, execute another for loop

Tags: language-agnostic

I am reading a text file and once I find a specific string, I want to exit the for loop.

```
  for@i=0 to 100
     if(string="0800")
        //execute code
     if(string="0900")
        //execute code
```

I then want to execute another for loop that still reads the same text file but is looking for a different parameter.

```
for@i=0 to 100
 if(string="SAN DIEGO")
    //execute code
 if(string="SAN FRANCISCO")
    //execute code
```

One for loop searches for a specific hour, the other for loop searches for a specific name.

This is an example of the format of the text file:

```
0800
SAN FRANCISCO
0900
SAN DIEGO
1600
OAKLAND
```

*Note that the hour and name are associated. i.e. 0800 is associated with SAN FRANCISCO, 0900 with SAN DIEGO,....

How can I set this up in the most efficient way possible?

Comment: You appear to already have the answer

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for, but I'm not sure

```
  for@i=0 to 100
     if(string="0800")
         if(string="SAN DIEGO")
             //execute code
         if(string="SAN FRANCISCO")
             //execute code
     if(string="0900")
         if(string="SAN DIEGO")
             //execute code
         if(string="SAN FRANCISCO")
             //execute code
```

Comment: Keep in mind that different cities can be associated with the same time. i.e. "OREGON" can be associated with hour 0800.

Comment: Could you please clarify that? If San Diego appears in the document with the number 0800 and also San Francisco does, this should execute the code for both.

Comment: The text file is going to have the hour then the name of the city, hour then name of the city...and so on. The hour and the city are associated. When I read an hour, I need to grab an external file associated with the hour. That is, whenever I read hour "0800", I need to grab "0800.pdf". After the hour is read, I read the name of the city, and execute code specific to that city name. I then need to repeat this for several hours and cities.

Comment: I posted a comment above ^ @Norhther

Comment: I really don't get why the above code don't work for your requirements. It simply gets the number, then grab whatever, and later execute the code for the city. If you need the number for the later execution of the code, save it before entering in the second if.

Comment: I execute the for loop for reading the hours, then it goes into the for loop that reads the city names. The problem is that I need to GO BACK to the for loop that reads the hours and then move on to the for loop that reads the city names. Repeat the process several times. @Norhther